# Why is this dictionary lookup method of processing a string into words slower than .split()?

Tags: python

When I wrote my first func to split a string up into words based on a list of separator characters, I thought I was being sloppy/lazy, since this would seemingly iterate over the whole string again for each character in the separator list, not to mention joining the list back into a string:

```
def splitText(text, list):
    for str in list:
        text = " ".join(text.split(str))
    arr = text.split(" ")
    cleaned = []
    for word in arr:
        if word != "":
            cleaned.append(word)
    return cleaned
```

So I wrote another version using a dictionary lookup as it iterated through the string a single time, epecting far better performance since a single O(1) lookup would be performed for each character in the string rather than the many splits and joins going on in the above func:

```
def splitTextFast(text, dict):
    arr = []
    progressIndex = 0
    for i, char in enumerate(text):
        if char in dict:
            arr.append(text[progressIndex:i])
        progressIndex = i + 1
    return arr
```

But to my surprise, `splitTextFast` was significantly slower. Why? Or, what mistake can I fix to create to most optimal version of this function? I just started using Python today, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

usage:

```
splitCharsArr = [",", ".", ";", "'", " "]
splitCharsDict = {",": True, ".": True, ";": True, "'": True, " ": True }
mockData = "one. two;  three four.five'six   ;seven,eight,nine"
wordList1 = splitText(mockData, splitCharsArr)
wordList2 = splitTextFast(mockData, splitCharsDict)
```

Comment: `splitTextFast` is iterating over `text` character by character, not word by word like `splitText`.

Comment: @chepner but to determine "words" from a string, `split()` must iterate character by character too beneath the surface, right?

Comment: The iteration is being done in optimized C code, rather than interpreted Python code.

Comment: And probably making use of hardware instructions for searching for a byte.

Comment: Your logic for `splitTextFast` isnt right, and `wordList2 ` produces `['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']` while wordlist1 produces `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']`. You have problem in these lines `if char in dict:
            arr.append(text[progressIndex:i])
        progressIndex = i + 1`